# Discord.js does not recognise the description of an embed

Tags: discord.js

I've been making a custom bot for a server I'm in, and all was going well until I encountered this runtime error in code that was seemingly working fine. Any tips?

Error:

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embeds[0].description: This field is required
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\arinb\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\arinb\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\arinb\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/949653134551154718/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [
        {
          title: null,
          type: 'rich',
          description: null,
          url: null,
          timestamp: null,
          color: null,
          fields: [],
          thumbnail: null,
          image: null,
          author: null,
          footer: null
        }
      ],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

code:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    let target = client.channels.cache.get(baseChannel) // gets channel 'general'
    let waitTrue = setWaitTime()
    if (!waitTrue) {
        console.log("sending success message")
        await interaction.reply({embeds: [
            new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("DARK_BUT_NOT_BLACK")
                .setTitle("Current Status")
                .setDescription("OFF")              
        ]})
        target.send({components: [defaultMessage(serverState)] })
    } else {
        interaction.reply({embeds : [waitTrue]})
    }
}


function setWaitTime() {
    state = serverState
    let retValue = false
    if (state.minecraft.players + state.hlServer.players != 0 ){
        retValue = {embeds: [
            new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("LUMINOUS_VIVID_PINK")
                .setDescription(`People are currently using the ${(state.minecraft.on) ? "minecraft": (state.hlServer.on) ? "TF2" : "ERROR"} server, try again later`)
                .setTitle("Queued your selection")
            ]
        }           
    }
    console.log(retValue)
    return retValue
```

I'm not sure why discord.js has not recognised the .setDescription(...) that has been applied to the embed, especially as this function was not changed since it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the `setWaitTime()` function, the value of the `retValue` variable is an object with an `embed` key and the value being the `MessageEmbed` so when you try to send `retValue`, what is actually happening is something like this:

```js
interaction.reply({
    embeds: {
        embeds: {
            new MessageEmbed()
            // ...
        }
    }
})
```

which is why this particular error is happening. So to fix it, instead of sending `retValue` as the embed property, just send it by itself like this:

```js
interaction.reply(retValue)
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end, I removed {embeds:[...]}, and just returned the new MessageEmbed

Comment: Yeah, that is also one way you could do it!